# @Html.EditorFor asp.net core doesn't work for file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I try to make `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.file)` to put file on web page (file is `IFormFile` type) in my ASP.NET Core application. But file is `null`, when i click submit,for some reason, and exception arises.For string everything is OK. Here is HTML code:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("tt", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">                
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.file)
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <button type="submit" id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.content)</div>        
}
```

controller code:

```
public ActionResult tt(Models.FileInfo f)
{
    var r = f.content1 + f.file.FileName;

    f.content = r;
    return View("Demo_index", f);
}
```

and model:

```
public class FileInfo
{
    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string content1 { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to make `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.file)` work? Or is there some similar way to make form with file uploading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're posting as `x-www-form-urlencoded`, which doesn't support file uploads. You need to use `multipart/form-data`, instead, which can be achieved via adding the `enctype` attribute to your form tag:

```
<form ... enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This is possible using `Html.BeginForm`, but you have to use an overload that requires you to specify a ton of parameters, and it's more pain than it's worth. Besides, in Core, using the tag helpers is much better anyways. Literally all you need is:

```
<form asp-action="tt" asp-controller="Home" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```

If you're doing a postback, i.e. to the same page you're already on, you can remove the `asp-action` and `asp-controller` attributes entirely. This will be processed by the built-in `FormTagHelper` and the right action and such will be generated for you.

FWIW, the same applies with your input as well. Instead of `EditorFor`, you can simply do:

```
<input asp-for="file" />
```

The `InputTagHelper` will fill in everything else.